# Установка прав роли | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role_1 = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
```

Хотел бы сделать так что-бы при написании cat роли выдавалось право администратора, или же  сделать так что сразу создавалась роль с правами админа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='role_id')
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    overwrite.read_messages = True
    await role1.edit(permissions=overwrite)
```

Comment: не работает, хотя возможно и я туповат.

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: код, хотя я не отрицаю свой тупизм, но пока я только учусь.

Comment: А где ошибка, скажите

Comment: Извиняюсь немного за другой воопрос, вообщем как выдать права я разобрался, но у меня встал встречный вопрос как узнать id роли которую я создал?

Comment: role = (создание роли)
role.id

Comment: role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='айди роли') role.id

Comment: Спасибо, хорошего дня!